# Builds, continuous integration and deployment for python projects?

Tags: python, deployment, continuous-integration

Could you please tell me which tools are used in python to build projects, as well as which continuous integration servers are used and how to deploy projects to the server?
What I mean is web projects, but will still be happy to know more of this information not only around the web.

Answer (score 6):

[Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/), formerly called Hudson, seems to be a very common choice for Python projects for continuous integration. I've used it for several years myself now, and I am still very happy with it. We also track pylint violations and code coverage in Jenkins - helping us keep the code quality up.

We have some automatic deployment to staging servers, but that's mostly custom built. Jenkins will let you run any shell script at several stages of the build, so if your deployment is not too complex, it's easy to integrate into Jenkins.